# Android layout - indirect children of TableRow as cells

Tags: android, layout

I have a table in an Android app serving as an timetable. Every lesson is a direct child element of TableRow, but I need to implement overlays over multiple lessons. So I tought I'd add FrameLayout in which would be the overlying View and lessons (cells of table). But there is a problem I can't find solution to - the cells don't inherit width of other cells, as they are not taken as children of the table (of its row).

Sorry if it's something obvious, but it is hard to search for a solution. Formulation of query about it to Google is a nightmare, it doesn"t give any relevant results. Thanks